# Trouble with connecting between Provider and Consumer

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, performancepoint

Having issues with connecting a PPS Filter WebPart (Provider) to a custom webpart (consumer).

Current Implementation:

```
public partial class SQLTextWebPart : WebPart , Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IFilterValues {
    private Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IFilterValues _provider = null;

    [ConnectionConsumer("Filter Consumer", "FilterConsumer")]
    public void FilterValueConsumer ( Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IFilterValues Provider ) {
        _provider = Provider;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender ( EventArgs e ) {
        EnsureChildControls();

        if ( _provider != null ) {
            lblFilterValue.Text = _provider.ParameterName + ": " + _provider.ParameterValues[ 0 ];
        }

        ////Execute BaseClass OnPreRender - Last
        //base.OnPreRender( e );
    }

    #region IFilterValues Members

    public string ParameterName {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public void SetConsumerParameters ( ReadOnlyCollection<Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ConsumerParameter> parameters ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then when i try to Send the Connection to the SQLTextWebPart or get a Connection from the PPS Filter, the window pops up and CorrelationID comes up.  Did a PowerShell query against the log files and got this result.  Still getting used to the formatting of SharePoint and its Exception handling, so maybe someone more intune with the formatting can assist in understanding it.

```
Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Logging Correlation Data
Level    : Medium
EventID  : xmnv
Message  : Name=Request (POST:http://sitecollection/sites/Portal/_layouts/15
           /AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=http://sitecollection/sites/Portal/Pages/S
           andbox.aspx&sWpId=g_91ed55d1_12e9_4773_b57c_6ae597ef291b&sGroupId=Tr
           ansformableBIDataProvider&tWpId=g_2ade4a5b_60f1_48b7_85a4_734f40b477
           57&tGroupId=FilterConsumer&xFormType=Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scor
           ecards.WebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDataProviderToFilterVal
           uesTransformer, Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls, 
           Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c&x
           FormInfo=&isMultiGroup=False&isConnected=False)

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Request Management
Level    : Medium
EventID  : adc7u
Message  : Mapping URI from 'http://sitecollection:80/sites/Portal/_layouts/
           15/AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsitecollection%2Fsites%2FPo
           rtal%2FPages%2FSandbox%2Easpx&sWpId=g%5F91ed55d1%5F12e9%5F4773%5Fb57
           c%5F6ae597ef291b&sGroupId=TransformableBIDataProvider&tWpId=g%5F2ade
           4a5b%5F60f1%5F48b7%5F85a4%5F734f40b47757&tGroupId=FilterConsumer&xFo
           rmType=Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecards%2EWebControls%2ETra
           nsforms%2ETransformableBIDataProviderToFilterValuesTransformer%2C%20
           Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecards%2EWebControls%2C%20Version
           %3D15%2E0%2E0%2E0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9b
           ce111e9429c&xFormInfo=&isMultiGroup=False&isConnected=False' to 'htt
           p://domainsite/sites/Portal/_layouts/15/AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=h
           ttp%3A%2F%2Fsitecollection%2Fsites%2FPortal%2FPag...

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Logging Correlation Data
Level    : Medium
EventID  : xmnv
Message  : Name=Request (POST:http://sitecollection:80/sites/Portal/_layouts
           /15/AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsitecollection%2Fsites%2FP
           ortal%2FPages%2FSandbox%2Easpx&sWpId=g%5F91ed55d1%5F12e9%5F4773%5Fb5
           7c%5F6ae597ef291b&sGroupId=TransformableBIDataProvider&tWpId=g%5F2ad
           e4a5b%5F60f1%5F48b7%5F85a4%5F734f40b47757&tGroupId=FilterConsumer&xF
           ormType=Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecards%2EWebControls%2ETr
           ansforms%2ETransformableBIDataProviderToFilterValuesTransformer%2C%2
           0Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecards%2EWebControls%2C%20Versio
           n%3D15%2E0%2E0%2E0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D71e9
           bce111e9429c&xFormInfo=&isMultiGroup=False&isConnected=False)

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Authentication Authorization
Level    : Medium
EventID  : agb9s
Message  : Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, 
           UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\username, ClaimsCount=50

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Logging Correlation Data
Level    : Medium
EventID  : xmnv
Message  : Site=/sites/Portal

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Files
Level    : High
EventID  : ak8dj
Message  : UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    
           at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContai
           ner(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean 
           copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SP
           FileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, 
           SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.
           SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.
           CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, 
           SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset 
           contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& 
           dbres)     at 
           Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 
           rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, 
           SPDocumentBindResults& dbres...

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Files
Level    : Medium
EventID  : aiv4w
Message  : Spent 0 ms to bind 3096 byte file stream

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Files
Level    : Medium
EventID  : ahjkm
Message  : Spent 0 ms to send 3096 byte file stream

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : General
Level    : Medium
EventID  : 8nca
Message  : Application error when access /_layouts/15/AspXform.aspx, 
           Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at Mic
           rosoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls.Transforms.Transforma
           bleBIDataProviderToFilterValuesTransformer.get_ConsumerParameters() 
               at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls.Transforms.
           TransformableBIDataProviderToFilterValuesUI.CreateContentRow()     
           at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls.Transforms.Tran
           sformerUIBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.Lo...

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Runtime
Level    : Unexpected
EventID  : tkau
Message  : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an 
           instance of an object.    at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.W
           ebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDataProviderToFilterValuesTrans
           former.get_ConsumerParameters()     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Sc
           orecards.WebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDataProviderToFilterV
           aluesUI.CreateContentRow()     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scoreca
           rds.WebControls.Transforms.TransformerUIBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
            at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web....

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : General
Level    : High
EventID  : ajlz0
Message  : Getting Error Message for Exception 
           System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 
           'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> 
           System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an 
           instance of an object.     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.
           WebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDataProviderToFilterValuesTran
           sformer.get_ConsumerParameters()     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.S
           corecards.WebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDataProviderToFilter
           ValuesUI.CreateContentRow()     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorec
           ards.WebControls.Transforms.TransformerUIBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)   
             at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at 
           System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive...

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : General
Level    : Monitorable
EventID  : aat87
Message  : 

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Request Management
Level    : High
EventID  : advu2
Message  : [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 04/09/2014 08:00:32.94, 
           Original Level: Verbose] Size of data: '{0}' bytes

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Request Management
Level    : High
EventID  : aht6j
Message  : [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Proxy response 
           duration: WFE '{0}', RM '{1}'

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Monitoring
Level    : Medium
EventID  : b4ly
Message  : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sitecollection:80/s
           ites/Portal/_layouts/15/AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fportaldev
           elopment%2Fsites%2FPortal%2FPages%2FSandbox%2Easpx&sWpId=g%5F91ed55d
           1%5F12e9%5F4773%5Fb57c%5F6ae597ef291b&sGroupId=TransformableBIDataPr
           ovider&tWpId=g%5F2ade4a5b%5F60f1%5F48b7%5F85a4%5F734f40b47757&tGroup
           Id=FilterConsumer&xFormType=Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecard
           s%2EWebControls%2ETransforms%2ETransformableBIDataProviderToFilterVa
           luesTransformer%2C%20Microsoft%2EPerformancePoint%2EScorecards%2EWeb
           Controls%2C%20Version%3D15%2E0%2E0%2E0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20P
           ublicKeyToken%3D71e9bce111e9429c&xFormInfo=&isMultiGroup=False&isCon
           nected=False)). Execution Time=71.8682

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Monitoring
Level    : Medium
EventID  : b4ly
Message  : Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sitecollection/site
           s/Portal/_layouts/15/AspXform.aspx?pageUrl=http://sitecollection/
           sites/Portal/Pages/Sandbox.aspx&sWpId=g_91ed55d1_12e9_4773_b57c_6ae5
           97ef291b&sGroupId=TransformableBIDataProvider&tWpId=g_2ade4a5b_60f1_
           48b7_85a4_734f40b47757&tGroupId=FilterConsumer&xFormType=Microsoft.P
           erformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls.Transforms.TransformableBIDat
           aProviderToFilterValuesTransformer, 
           Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.WebControls, 
           Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c&x
           FormInfo=&isMultiGroup=False&isConnected=False)). Execution 
           Time=75.3427
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked through all the problems with my connection and wrote up a Q&A style posting in SharePoint Exchange, [Visual Web Part as consumer of PPS Filter Provider](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/95925/24279).

In case others land on this posting, they should be able to read up on the steps to get a successful implementation.